# Mad king riddle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

I was asked of a similar riddle to the one you posted where a mad king asks you to kill a chicken but would have to use the same method on you : how do you survive?

I’ve been thinking of this for days and I can’t think of the logical explanation that seems to be the answer. Could you tell me??

Answer (score 3):

> Place a fully working car on unused railroad tracks and put the chicken inside. Then start up an empty train engine 1 km away so that it's on a collision course with the car. The chicken won't survive the collision, but a human can simply drive the car off the tracks and survive.

Answer (score 0):

Suffocate the chicken with its own feathers (humans don’t have feathers).
More specifically, pluck the chicken, and then stuff the feathers in its mouth.